# What does BLAS DGEMV error code -6 mean?

Tags: r, lapack, blas

I have a program that runs through R but uses the BLAS routines. It runs through correctly about 8 times but then throws an error:

> BLAS/LAPACK routine 'DGEMV ' gave error code -6

What does this error code mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R defines the XERBLA function as

```
void F77_NAME(xerbla)(const char *srname, int *info)
{
   /* srname is not null-terminated.  It should be 6 characters. */
    char buf[7];
    strncpy(buf, srname, 6);
    buf[6] = '\0';
    error(_("BLAS/LAPACK routine '%6s' gave error code %d"), buf, -(*info));
}
```

from the src/main/print.c file.

the Netlib version of dgemv.f shows that only the input parameters are checked.  A code of 6 shows a problem with either the LDA or M parameter.

```
*...
  ELSE IF (LDA.LT.MAX(1,M)) THEN
      INFO = 6
*...
  END IF
  IF (INFO.NE.0) THEN
      CALL XERBLA('DGEMV ',INFO)
      RETURN
```

So it appears that R takes the negative of the BLAS error code, which I think causes lots of confusion.  I think this answers my question but not my problem, since it works several times with the same parameters before the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

[DGEMV](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dgemv.f) does not return any error codes.

This [bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=2822) implies that the error is coming from `R` itself.

Perhaps you should file a bug against `R`.

Comment: BLAS has an error handler called XERBLA.  R overwrites XERBLA to pass on error messages.  The error is called from the info variable, from what I can see.

Comment: Looks like you got the answer there.